# "cannot access javax.servlet.Filter" error when using Spring Security with Spring Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have Spring Gateway and Spring Security together because I want to secure my gateway. But after implementing the following class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, the project throws

> java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filter

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetails = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("foo").password(passwordEncoder().encode("bar")).build();
        
        userDetails.createUser(user);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetails).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gabriel</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gateway-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Spring Cloud Gateway [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/):

> Spring Cloud Gateway requires the Netty runtime provided by Spring Boot and Spring Webflux. It does not work in a traditional Servlet Container or when built as a WAR.

Extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is for servlet based applications.

You should instead configure [Spring Security for reactive applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.6/reference/html5/#reactive-applications).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class HelloWebfluxSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("foo").password(passwordEncoder().encode("bar")).build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember using the way I showed but with Zuul. However, it seems Spring 2.4 does not support Zuul anymore. At least that was what I read somewhere, and I did have issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this dependency and that still works.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```