# An expected CSRF token cannot be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm trying to disable Spring security into latest Spring Cloud using this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfigSec extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/**");
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
    main:
        allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
security:
    ignored=/**:
    enable-csrf: false
```

I also tried to add:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

But it's not working.

I get error: `An expected CSRF token cannot be found`

```
18:16:24.537 [boundedElastic-2] DEBUG DefaultWebSessionManager[lambda$createWebSession$3:94] - Created new WebSession.
18:16:24.540 [boundedElastic-2] DEBUG HttpWebHandlerAdapter[traceDebug:91] - [1ffd0a30] Completed 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: It seems like your application is reactive, based on the logs `Created new WebSession`. You do not configure security in reactive applications by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268107/cannot-access-javax-servlet-filter-error-when-using-spring-security-with-sprin/67269039#67269039

Comment: Hi Peter, did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

may be you pom.xml have a dependency confict,such as dependency about "oauth2"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Exclude the MVC dependencies from pom.xml

And add:

```
spring:
 main:
  web-application-type: reactive
```

This worked for me; I was getting CSRF error as spring security used in Spring MVC was enabled.

Answer (score -1):

### I Fixed this by

```
    @Bean
  SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
    ServerHttpSecurity http,
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository
){
return http
...
.csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(
  CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
.build(); 
}

@Bean
WebFilter csrfWebFilter() {
//A filter with the only purpose of subscribing to the CsrfToken reactive stream and ensuring its value is extracted correctly
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
      exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> Mono.defer(() -> {
        Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken =
          exchange.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        return csrfToken != null ? csrfToken.then() : Mono.empty();
      }));
      return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```