# Spring cloud with spring security not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

**GOAL**

I want to use spring security with the cloud gateway to authenticate and authorize all the requests going to the microservices.

**PROBLEM**

The login post method for security works when this is just a `spring-boot-starter-web` microservice and other endpoints also work. But when I add the  `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` to the pom the authentication and authorization do not work.

**POM file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sagar</groupId>
    <artifactId>apigateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apigateway</name>
    <description>apigateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.31</kotlin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**AppSecurityConfig**

```
package com.sagar.apigateway.security

import com.sagar.apigateway.Configs
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class AppSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var appUserService: AppUserService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var configs: Configs

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        @Suppress("SimpleRedundantLet")
        http?.let {
            it
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), configs))
                .addFilterAfter(JWTVerifier(configs), JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/database").hasAuthority(AppUserPermission.ADMIN_WRITE.permission)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/database").hasAuthority(AppUserPermission.ADMIN_WRITE.permission)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/database").hasAuthority(AppUserPermission.ADMIN_WRITE.permission)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/database")
                .hasAnyRole(AppUserRole.ADMIN.name, AppUserRole.ADMIN_TRAINEE.name)
                .antMatchers(
                    "/v2/api-docs",
                    "/swagger-ui/index.html",
                    "/swagger-ui/**",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/webjars/**",
                    "/hello/sendEmail"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider())
    }

    @Bean
    fun authProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider {
        val daoAuthProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        daoAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        daoAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService)
        return daoAuthProvider
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the authentication and authorization do not work? Do you get an error or some other type of unexpected behaviour?

Comment: the /login gives me a CSRF token required error.  But as you can see the csrf() is disabled. So i debugged the code and found that `override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {` method is never called.

Comment: Spring Cloud Gateway uses Spring WebFlux. You are using the servlet-based security configuration in a reactive application. You can see the solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268107/cannot-access-javax-servlet-filter-error-when-using-spring-security-with-sprin/67269039#67269039